# Why does IDEA report possible NullPointerException?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception

Why is null checking with auxiliary variable protecting against  `NullPointerException`, while direct null checking is not?

---

Consider these two blocks of code:

```
public boolean passwordMatch1(Player player, String password) {
    if (LoggedPlayer.getLoggedPlayer(player) != null) {
        return LoggedPlayer.getLoggedPlayer(player).getPassword().equals(password);
    }
    return false;
}
```

and

```
public boolean passwordMatch2(Player player, String password) {
    LoggedPlayer p = LoggedPlayer.getLoggedPlayer(player);
    if (p != null) {
        return p.getPassword().equals(password);
    }
    return false;
}
```

They are doing exactly the same thing, method `passwordMatch2` uses auxiliary variable of `LoggedPlayer` called `p`, while method `passwordMatch1` is checking for null directly.

Method `LoggedPlayer.getLoggedPlayer(Player player)` is known to return `null` when no appropriate `LoggedPlayer` instance is found.

---

IDEA is reporting a warning in `passwordMatch1`:

> Method invocation 'getPassword' may produce
>   'java.lang.NullPointerException

while `passwordMatch2` has no warning.

(*IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.2*)

Comment: If the underlying `LoggedPlayer.getLoggedPlayer()` data structure is capable of changing between calls (like in a multi-threaded context) then the second call in `passwordMatch1` could return a null value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider a possible (but bad) implementation of `LoggedPlayer.getLoggedPlayer`.

```
public static LoggedPlayer getLoggedPlayer(Player player) {
   return Math.random() < 0.500 ? new LoggedPlayer() : null;
}
```

That is to say, `getLoggedPlayer` may not be pure, and separate invocations of it may return different values.

Answer (score 1):

There's limitations in static analysis.  Typically, static analysis won't be able to reliably detect and contextualize that you've wrapped a potentially unsafe operation in a safe check.

Lexers are simple.  They will tokenize every symbol that they see, and  go from there.  From there, they won't be able to say, "Oh, we've already checked this invocation", and they won't be able to reliably report on its safety.

Another issue would be if your method wasn't idempotent, a fact that ***cannot*** be determined in static analysis.  If `LoggedPlayer.getLoggedPlayer(player)` returned a different value on any given invocation (such as in @Nick's fantastic example), then the lexer would miss reporting on that case.